# Timber Plugin for use in non-WordPress Twig

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

If possible, how can I use Timber filters on non-WordPress twig sites? I'd like to be able to just mockup sites that I intend on using with WordPress + Timber, but without the database.

Is this possible?

I'm thinking specifically with responsive filters such as:

```
<img src={{ "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"|resize(640, 480)}}>
```

or

```
<img src={{ "https://placeimg.com/640/480/any"|resize(640, 480)|letterbox(640, 480, '#ffff00') }}>
```

Also, the Timber Sugar plugin and the lorem ipsum feature is useful for development.

Comment: Timber is an implementation of Twig for Wordpress. Why don't you use directly Twig and create your custom functions and filters ?

Comment: Any chance you can you point me in the direction on how to reuse the Timber functions? I can roughly get around twig, but creating my own custom functions would be a beast for me. I appreciate the answer.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#creating-an-extension)

Comment: Why? Using Wordpress is going to make this much easyer and less time intensive for you.